# How to Handle IQKeyboardManager Done button action in toolbar?

Tags: ios, swift, iqkeyboardmanager

I am new in ios I work on iqkeyboardmanager and I want to access Done button action in IQKeyboardManager.

Comment: Well i dont think you can handle the done button from IQKeyboard but if you want to perform something you can put you custom action on the `Return key` in the keyboard

Comment: but i want handle Done button action as well

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can handle clicks of done, next and previous button

```
[textField.keyboardToolbar.previousBarButton setTarget:self action:@selector(previousAction:)];
[textField.keyboardToolbar.nextBarButton setTarget:self action:@selector(nextAction:)];
[textField.keyboardToolbar.doneBarButton setTarget:self action:@selector(doneAction:)];
```

In swift:

```
customField.keyboardToolbar.doneBarButton.setTarget(self, action: #selector(doneButtonClicked))

func doneButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        //your code when clicked on done
}
```

Comment: I got error in swift "Value of type 'UITextField' has no member 'keyboardToolbar'" while using above method

Comment: @Lalit Kumar i am getting this error - Property 'keyboardToolbar' not found on object of type 'IQDropDownTextField *'

Comment: after adding #import "IQKeyboardManager.h" in header it works. :)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Enjoying the day.

Answer (score 19):

you can use UITextViewDelegate

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

 }
```

Comment: But this delegate function is called even if user didn't tap *Done* button. I can just tap the screen and this function will fire too.

Comment: This delegate may call from return key of keyboard, so its not good solution.

Answer (score 17):

You can import

```
import IQKeyboardManager
```

in required file and after that

```
vc1Textfield.addDoneOnKeyboard(withTarget: self, action: #selector(doneButtonClicked))
```

here vc1Textfield is my textfield and doneButtonClicked definition is given below:

```
@objc func doneButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) { }
```

Hope it help someone!!! Happy Coding....

Answer (score 6):

I will try to describe in a more convenient way:

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

class EditPostViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var commentTextView: UITextView!


   override func awakeFromNib() {
      IQKeyboardManager.shared.toolbarDoneBarButtonItemText = "Send Comment"
      commentTextView.delegate = self
   }

   @objc func didPressOnDoneButton() {
      commentTextView.resignFirstResponder()
      sendComment()
   }

}

extension EditPostViewCell: UITextViewDelegate {

   public func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
      let invocation = IQInvocation(self, #selector(didPressOnDoneButton))
      textView.keyboardToolbar.doneBarButton.invocation = invocation
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First:
 `import the IQKeyboardManager.h`

Then:

`[self.textField.keyboardToolbar.doneBarButton setTarget:self action:@selector(doneAction:)];`

Answer (score 0):

xcode 11.
Make **Action** connection textField with code.

```
@IBAction func yourName(_ sender: Any){
// Your code
}
```

[Connections inspector screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qerf.png)